# Can comparing content in CKEDITOR on a change event impact performance?

Tags: ckeditor

From https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change

> If it is important not to get the change event fired too often, you should compare the previous and the current editor content inside the event listener. It is not recommended to do that on every change event.

I don't understand the above ... is there possibly a typo?

Is it trying to say that a call such as [checkDirty](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-checkDirty) on every change event could result in poor performance?

Would using an interval timer be a good approach to limit the number of `checkDirty` calls made.

For example, do not call checkDirty unless at least 1 second had passed from its last invocation?

The use case I have is enabling or disabling a save button based on the editor content differing from its last saved state.

Comment: Why can't you have the save button always enabled?

Comment: @Wizard Yes, I could do that.  It would be nice though to have some visual indicator that the current editor content is in fact saved.

Answer (score 1):

I deal with this situation by always having the save button enabled and:

1) Every time a user presses the save button, I alert him that the contents have been saved and I clear the dirty flag:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.resetDirty();
```

2) I register an `onbeforeunload` event handler to alert him if he tries to exit the webpage having unsaved data:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.checkDirty()) {
        return 'You will lose the changes made in the editor if you don't save them.';
    }
}
```